# Same name in 2 methods in 2 different interfaces, why not 1 implementation?

Tags: c#, interface

If I have 2 methods with the same name, but with different return types. They are inherited by a class from 2 interfaces. This class can provide 1 implementation for both if the return type for implementation conforms to return type in both interfaces.

For example, `String` type implements both methods: `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<char>`. The implementation for `String` type contains just one implementation for `GetEnumerator`.

```
public CharEnumerator GetEnumerator();
```

I believe this is possible because `CharEnumerator` implements both `IEnumerator` and `IEnumerator<char>`

```
public CharEnumerator: IEnumerator, IEnumerator<char>
```

However, a similar code in my application below gives me a compilation error,

```
interface Ia { IEnumerator o();}
interface Ib { IEnumerator<int> o();}
class e : IEnumerator, IEnumerator<int>{}
class c : Ia, Ib { public e o() { return new e(); } }
```

If I do a F12 on String type in Visual Studio, I see something like below,
[image]

As you can see, there is only 1 implicit implementation of `GetEnumerator()`, no explicit implementations there

Comment: The C# language does not support return type co-variance.  Which is why the String class has *two* GetEnumerator() methods.  The second one is an explicit implementation method, necessary to avoid the ambiguity.  And why you need two as well.

Comment: @HansPassant I think *both* interfaces are implemented explicitly. `string.GetEnumerator` actually returns a `CharEnumerator` which would not comply with any of the two interface contracts. I'm guessing this is legacy code from C#1

Comment: @HansPassant Why does then my code fail to compile, the type `e` does derive from `IEnumerable` as well as `IEnumerable<>`

Comment: You are right.  They tried to get rid of CharEnumerator in .NETCore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String does not *implicitly* implement `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<char>`. It does so explicitly, which means you can only access the methods through an `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<char>` reference.

The method `CharEnumerator GetEnumerator()` implements neither interface because the return type is not a `IEnumerator` or a `IEnumerator<T>`; `CharEnumerator` is one possible `IEnumerator` but the interface is asking for *any* `IEnumerator`.

Explicit interfaces are very useful, you have just stumbled on one of the features they provide; implementing in one class different interfaces that define a method with the same name:

```
interface IFoo
{
    IFoo Frob();
}

interface IBar
{
    IBar Frob();
}

public class Blah: IFoo, IBar
{
    Foo IFoo.Frob() => new Foo();
    Bar IBar.Frob() => new Bar();
    void Frob();
}
```

And now, you'll get the following behavior:

```
var b = new Blah();
b.Frob(); //returns nothing, this method is not implementing any of the two interfaces.
(b as IBar).Frob(); //returns a bar
(b as IFoo).Frob(); //returns a foo
```

Comment: Please see edited question above. Visual Studio shows just one implicit implementation of GetEnumerator()

Comment: @EagerToLearn No, that is not an implicit implementation. `CharEnumerator GetEnumerator()` does not implement *any* interface. See edits to my example to see a similar situation. Explicit implementations are not shown when inspecting the type definition.

Comment: Got it. So, string provides `CharEnumerator GetEnumerator()` in addition to 2 explicit implementations, one for each `IEnumerable` and `IEumerable<char>`. But why not simply make `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()` explicit, there by making `IEnumerable<char>.GetEnumerator()` available?

Comment: @EagerToLearn Because `string` is in the framework since day one, iterators and generics made it into the language later on.

Comment: Thanks. This clarifies all. The MSDN page for String class does show 1 GetEnumerator() method and 2 explicit method implementations on type.